# How to avoid get(id) method invoked if verify() return Mono.error(TheException())

Tags: kotlin, project-reactor

First need to `verify()` something, if all ok then invoke `get(id)` method to get the entity, otherwise no need to invoke `get(id)`. How to write the method `verifyThenGet(id)` code?

```
fun verifyThenGet(id: Int) : Mono<MyEntity> {
    return verify().then(get(id)) // also invoke get(id) even verify failed
}

// return Mono.empty() if success to verify,
// otherwise return Mono.error(TheException())
fun verify() : Mono<Void>

// get the entiry
fun get(id: Int) : Mono<MyEntity>
```

Comment: Why does `verify()` return `Mono<Void>` in the first place? Why `Void` (especially in Kotlin)?

Comment: because if verify ok, do not need to return anything, just complete signal.

Comment: If it fails to compile, you need to read the error message from the compiler, and to post it if you don't understand it. And post the actual code, too. `int` doesn't exist in Kotlin.

Comment: @JBNizet correct int to Int. Sorry I make a wrong question, I change it again。

Comment: It's perfectly normal for get(id) to be invoked. get(id) just creates a Mono. It doesn't actually do anything. The actual work (i.e. getting the entity by querying the database) will happen when a subscriber subscribes to the Mono returned by get(id). But that won't happen if verify() returns an error Mono.

Comment: That's real. But I need to use Mockito to verify the `get(id)` method invoked times in my unit test. I need to sure this `get(id)` method never invoked if `verify()` failed. Finally I use this code `verify().then(Mono.just(0).flatMap { get(id) })`, but `Mono.just(0)` is really noise. I thing `verify().then { get(id) }` is perfect, but reactor not support this function now. I dont know why. I also summit a [issue-1312](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/1312) to reactor to ask why.

Answer (score -1):

Given the comments on your code, looks like your `verify` method should have the following signature:

```
fun verify(): Unit
```

In Kotlin, usually, you just would throw an `Exception` instead of return an error (maybe you have your own error type to return? in which case maybe return `MyError?` if you really want that).

`get` should probably look like this:

```
fun get(id: Int): MyEntity?
```

The `?` at the end of the type name means the return value is optional, so it may be `null`.

To combine `verify` with your `get` function is trivial:

```
fun verifyThenGet(id: Int): MyEntity? {
    verify()
    return get(id)
}
```

Comment: To be clear, my question code is reactive program code, all the method need to be reactive. So the return value is designed to Mono.

Comment: How do you want us to know that if you forget to mention that in your question?